# Sitecore 8 Solr SwitchOnRebuidIndex

Tags: solr, sitecore, sitecore8

We have a Sitecore 8 Update 5 solution and Solr 5.3.1.
We want to rebuild an index in a separate core so the rebuilding does not affect the search index that is currently used. Once the rebuilding and the optimization of the index completes, Sitecore switches the two cores, and the rebuilt and optimized index is used.

I try to follow this [link](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore%20experience%20platform/search%20and%20indexing/switch%20solr%20indexes)
but I received next exception when I'm trying to rebuil my index from Control Panel :

```html
    Job started: Index_Update_IndexName=website_web_general_index|#Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> SolrNet.Exceptions.SolrConnectionException: <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>

<p>Problem accessing /solr/websiteCore_sec/update. Reason:

<pre>    Not Found</pre></p><hr><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><hr/>

</body>
</html>
 ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at HttpWebAdapters.Adapters.HttpWebRequestAdapter.GetResponse()
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.GetResponse(IHttpWebRequest request)
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.PostStream(String relativeUrl, String contentType, Stream content, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.PostStream(String relativeUrl, String contentType, Stream content, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.Post(String relativeUrl, String s)
   at SolrNet.Commands.DeleteCommand.Execute(ISolrConnection connection)
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrBasicServer`1.SendAndParseHeader(ISolrCommand cmd)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex.Reset(ISolrOperations`1 operations, String coreName)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex.PerformRebuild(Boolean resetIndex, Boolean optimizeOnComplete, IndexingOptions indexingOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex.Rebuild(Boolean resetIndex, Boolean optimizeOnComplete)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Jobs.Job.ThreadEntry(Object state)
```

If I try to access these links:

```
 http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/WebsiteCore_Sec/update?commit=true and
 http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/WebsiteCore/update?commit=true
```

I get :

```html
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">3</int>
</lst>
</response>
```

Comment: Do you run your Solr on Linux? Can it be that it's lowercase **`w`** in `Problem accessing /solr/**w**ebsiteCore_sec/update` is the issue?

Comment: Is running on Windows, my start letter is uppercase.

Comment: The error message you posted says "websiteCore_sec" with lowercase - that's why I asked. I worked with SwitchOnRebuild mode 1 year ago and didn't have any issues. Even blogged about it http://www.skillcore.net/sitecore/using-switchonrebuildsolrsearchindex-solr-provider-for-sitecore

Comment: I just put replace name of the client with  "website" that's why I have websiteCore_sec

Comment: Solr indexing working okay otherwise?  You have the "ContentSearch.Solr.ServiceBaseAddress" in the "Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config" file set to point to your localhost?

Comment: Yeh I have it, now it's working, I restarted my computer and works fine, strange behaviour. Marek I  follow your blogposr,from there I was inspiring.